# VB.Net - Remove lines longer than 5 characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

Suprisingly i haven't found any threads online about this....

In my TextBox1 i have this:

```
computer
desk
alphabet
sex
pencil
book
apple
```

I want to remove all lines that have more characters than `5`, so this will remain:

```
desk
sex
book
apple
```

This seems like a job for Regex, but i don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: This is not a proper regex job to count characters. You can easily check the string length with string methods. Have you tried anything?

Comment: what kind of textbox? web forms? winforms? This does actually influence the best solution for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.{5}.+` is a regular expression that matches 6 more more of any character.

You could use that.

But really, if `s` is a String containing all the words then use `s.Split` to divide the string up into words, then test each element in a loop. You may as well use `w.Length` where `w` is one of the words.

Comment: Works perfectly, but how do i make it repeat (it only gets one string)? I know it's `*` character, but where to put it? I am beginner at VB.Net...